# Go package not in $GOROOT

Tags: go

I'm using the following Go module to build an application:

`github.com/martinlindhe/unit`

Right now, the Go code is very simple; I'm just trying to get the environment set up for the real work:

```
import(
    "fmt"
    "unit"
    
)

foo := unit.FromFahrenheit(100)
fmt.Println("100 fahrenheit in celsius = ", foo.Celsius())
```

In go.mod:

```
go 1.17

require github.com/martinlindhe/unit v0.0.0-20210313160520-19b60e03648d
```

Executing either `go build` or `go get` results in:

`package unit is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/unit)`

Running `go mod download` executes without error. The go.sum file seems to be correct, all the necessary dependencies exist.

The environment is the latest version of VS Code, Go installed via homebrew on MacOS Big Sur 11.5.2

There must be something obvious I'm missing. I've not had this problem with other apps I've written.

Comment: Import it as "github.com/martinlindhe/unit", not just "unit"

Comment: AHA! Thanks! I was doing this way too late last night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The import path is not right. [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/03wxCAsZ8A_W).

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/martinlindhe/unit"
)

func main() {
        foo := unit.FromFahrenheit(100)
        fmt.Println("100 fahrenheit in celsius = ", foo.Celsius())

}
```